# Regex expression not matching identical string when passed from XAML

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, xaml, converters

I have this regex expression on my xaml `Trip\: I\> \(50\-1\)` that is being passed to a converter. When I debug the converter and look at how the regex turns out it becomes `Trip: I> (50-1)` which is exactly what I want. I am then trying to match this regex (`searchRegex` variable) to an identical string seen below:

```cs
if (searchRegex.IsMatch("Trip: I> (50-1)"))
{
    return true;
}
```

This expression never returns true. Any suggestions why this would be when both are identical?

EDIT:

This is the xml where the regex is set

```xml
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActiveAlarms, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
    AncestorType={x:Type tagsviews:Indicator}}, 
    Converter={StaticResource ActiveAlarmsConverter}, 
    ConverterParameter='Trip\: I\> \(50\-1\)'}" 
    Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="FaultLine" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

and this is how I convert to regex on the Converter, where`parameter` is the `ConverterParameter` from the DataTrigger above

```cs
Regex searchRegex = new Regex((string)parameter);
```

Comment: First problem is you are trying to regex a structured serialized language. However that aside, you have not included the xml you are parsing. We have no way to actually check and verify anything.

Comment: Please also include how you exactly construct `searchRegex`

Comment: Your regular expression does not match the subject string.

Comment: Try `Trip\\: I\\\> \\\(50\\-1\\\)` or use `Regex.Escape`

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping your expression

```
"Trip\\: I\\\> \\\(50\\-1\\\)"
```

Or use [`Regex.Escape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-5.0)

> Escapes a minimal set of characters `(`, `\`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `|`, `{`, `[`, `(` ,`)`, `^`, `$`,
> `.`, `#`, and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes. This
> instructs the regular expression engine to interpret these characters
> literally rather than as metacharacters.